# limit points of a subset of a compact set

Tags: real-analysis

so I'm confused. I know that any infinite subset of a compact set $X$ should have a limit point in $X$. I wonder why it is not true that all the limit points of any subset $E$ of a compact set $X$ belong to $X$? If any limit point $p$ of $E$ does not belong to $X$, it means that it belongs to the complement of $X$ which is an open set. Then there is a neighborhood around $p$ which has no intersection with $X$ therefore not with $E$ too, contradicting the definition of a limit point. Where am I mistaken? thx in advance

Comment: You are not mistaken, in fact for any closed set $X$ the limit points of a subset $E\subset X$ are contained in $X$.

Comment: Is the space you're considering Hausdorff or a general topological space?

Comment: @Chrystomath: It's a general topological space. Have no experience with Hausdorff space to be honest.

Comment: @FlorisClaassens: I was just confused why Rudin had it as a theorem, I thought the extension of the theorem to any subset(not only infinite ones) was false.

Comment: @shota kobakhidze, I did some quick extra research, and this has a lot to do with the definition of a limit point. Some point $x$ is a limit point of $E$ if every neighbourhood of $x$ contains a point of $E$ other then $x$ itself. By this definition, clearly if $E$ is finite it has no limit points.

Comment: @FlorisClaassens, Yes, exactly. That is why the theorem is only stated about infinite sets. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If $X$ is not a Hausdorff space, then compact sets need not be closed. So Floris' comment, though correct, would not apply to compact sets.

Comment: @Chrystomath, Really? what about Heine-Borel theorem?

Comment: The Heine-Borel theorem is for $\mathbb{R}^n$, or when generalized, to complete metric spaces. It does not apply to $\mathbb{Q}$ for example.

Comment: @Chrystomath, $Q$ is not even compact I suppose, or what do you mean?

Comment: Closed and bounded subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ are not compact.